# Untrusted Enterprise Developer - Solving Non-Manual way

Tags: ios, certificate

On the new iOS 10, I am getting an "Untrusted Enterprise Developer" alert stating that "Until this developer has been trusted, their enterprise apps will not be available for use."

I have gone to this way :-

> Settings.app -> General -> Profile -> Select Profile -> Trust

And able to trust the certificate but I dont want any user to do Manually .

Does anyone know how I can trust my distribution certificate on this device and test my enterprise apps which is not this Manual way?

Here they are saying I can do it via MDM way , is that possible? :- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html